# How can I make Ruby rake display the full backtrace on uncaught exception

Tags: exception, rake, backtrace

As you may know rake swallows the full backtrace on uncaught exception. If I want to have a full backtrace, I need to add the --trace option. I find this very annoying because some of my tasks take long time to run (up to 6 hours), when it crashes I don't have any debugging info.  I need to run it again with the --trace.  On top of that, the system may not be in the same state as when the error occurred, so it may not show afterward. I always have to add --trace on any tasks. This displasy stuff that I don't want to see when the task is executed.

Is there a way to change this default behaviour? (which I don't think is useful at all)

Answer (score 3):

Supposedly you can go into the Rakefile and add:

```
Rake.application.options.trace = true
```

I discovered this [here](http://pivotallabs.com/users/brian/blog/articles/301-get-rake-to-always-show-the-error-stack-trace-for-your-project) quite by accident while searching for a solution to one of my own issues I'm having.

Comment: Thanks for the information but I still have all the debug info to the stdout as the list of tasks that I execute. 
This pollutes the output. In fact this is very annoying to me since I use it in my cron jobs. And each time that I get an output in my cronjob I receive an email.